# Using Google Analytics APIs to create charts comparing data across date ranges

Tags: javascript, charts, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the Google Analytics API to create a custom analytics dashboard and need to include an audience overview comparison like this:

[image: GA audience overview comparison]

I'm mostly using the GA Embed API. I couldn't find an obvious way to create a date range comparison chart like this on a single Embed DataChart. I tried a few different approaches to create such a chart:

- passing multiple date ranges into the Embed DataChart: doesn't seem to use Reporting v4 which is required for multiple date ranges
- using the third party chart.js library: couldn't get it to look like GA charts
- using the GA reporting and GA charts APIs directly to generate a single chart with two lines: couldn't get it to look right
- creating two GA Embed DataCharts and superimposing one on the other

The last approach is the only one with which I could create a chart almost exactly like those in the image above. Unfortunately I still have two problems with this approach:

- Too many GA queries slowing page loading: one query for the main chart and one for the overlay, but also two reporting queries to get the chart data first in order to synchronise their vertical scales, so that's a total of 4 queries per chart. I might be able to reduce this to 3 if it's possible to use Reporting v4 at the same time as the embed API but that would still be 8 unnecessary queries across all the charts.
- In GA comparison charts, if there is a date range mismatch the shorter date range cuts off and the two lines match up from a date perspective. I don't think this is possible using Embed DataCharts because the query is tied to the chart so I can't pad the data out with zeros before one of the charts is displayed.

My current plan is to use the Reporting and Chart APIs directly to reduce the number of queries and enable me to match the date ranges for comparison, although I think the Embed DataChart must work some magic when it ties together a timeline query & chart because I'm struggling to map the data and get the chart to be labelled as in the above image.

Is there a better way to generate one of these date range comparison charts using Google's APIs?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `reporting api V4` to get data by using `ga:date` dimension against any `metric` that you want. then you can use any charting library to plot graphs , it's up to the charting library you use for superimposing multiple plots